# How to delete all Files on an FTP Server

Tags: python, bash, ftp

I need to write a script which deletes all files on an FTP server without changing the directory structure.

Since there is no `find` command or similar.

I tried using `lftp` but got stuck since the `rm -r` is not flexible enough.

Anyway it could be bash or python.

I do not have ssh access to that server. FTP only.

Comment: I do not have any file pattern so `rm -rf` would delete directories.

Comment: I do not have any pattern like `*.txt` so `mdelete *` would delete directories as well.

Comment: Like I said: without changing the directory structure, yes. I want to keep them.

Answer (score 2):

How is could be done in Python. You did not give any code, so I give the basics only, no code as well:

- put the root folder in a list
- pop one item off the list

  - list the item
  - append the directories in this listing to the list
  - delete the files in the listing.
- repeat the second step incl. substeps until the list is empty

Helpful: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html